# C++/Qt getting the value of pointer to a pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have what I think is a pointer to a pointer and want to get the object the pointer, the pointer is pointing too. or get the pointer that the pointer is pointing to which is an object pointer.

```
QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();
ui->GraphicsView->setScene(scene);
loc.setPointer(&scene);
```

the location class, object loc.

```
setPointer(QGraphicsScene* x) {
    scene = x;
}
```

it says QGraphicsScene** cannot be converted to QGraphicsScene*. So Im assuming that ** means a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();
ui->GraphicsView->setScene(scene);
loc.setPointer(scene);
```

&scene is a pointer to pointer of scene

Comment: To be exact: `&scene` takes the address of the pointer `scene`, which in turn is a pointer to a pointer to a scene.